# Where does SSMS Last database backup date come from?

Tags: sql-server

The backup date for several of my databases do not appear in msdb.dbo.back upset yet the correct date appears in SSMS when I select a db name, right click, properties, there in the general tab is the correct date. Where does SQL Server get this date?

Answer (score 2):

> Where does SQL Server get this date?

SSMS behind the scenes uses `msdb.dbo.backupset` to populate the data in the Properties page `Last Database Backup`. Note that the SSMS properties page does not give info about filegroup backup. It only gives info about full, diff or log backup.

You can use [this script to retrieve SQL Server database backup history and no backups details](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1601/script-to-retrieve-sql-server-database-backup-history-and-no-backups/)

Comment: As noted in my question msdb.dbo.backupset is not giving me the last backup for all the databases yet a correct date appears in SSMS.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits are you sure that you have successful backups ? `backupset` does not contain failed backup info.

Comment: Yes because we use the backups to restore to a reporting system.

Comment: Who checked the answer as correct? I did not and Kin did not read my question which stated that the table backupset was not working for me.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits are you looking at the right instance. There is no way that `msdb.dbo.backupset` will be empty and the general tab is showing correct date. Post screen shots so we can verify. We dont have access to your servers, so this is the best guess that we can make.